# Write to xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-file

I just need to create and write to an XML file after clicking a button in my app. The code I have works if it's just a pure Java file, but if I try to run it in the emulator as part of the app, it doesn't do anything. I don't get any errors, it simply doesn't do anything.

I tried creating an implements interface and doing it that way but I got the same result.

Here's the relevant part of my code right now.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    add_defect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try {

                    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    // Add this and a bunch of other stuff that I edited out
                    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
                    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("root");
                    doc.appendChild(rootElement);


                    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\soandso\\Documents\\myXml.xml"));

                    // Output to console for testing
                    //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

                    transformer.transform(source, result);

                } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
                    pce.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
                    tfe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
            }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code runs **on an Android device**, not a Windows computer or within Android Studio.

Therefore, `C:\\Users\\soandso\\Documents\\myXml.xml` does not exist, and you should be getting a Logcat error saying exactly that.

You should read about [File Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) on Android because you'll also need to grant yourself permission to write to the device storage.